# unlimited scrolling up from default linux command line

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, debian

I am looking to increase the default size of the scrolling up buffer from linux command line. It is a Debian server without gui.

I don't find related option in bashrc and I don't even know if there is other configuration file for the default prompt alt+f1 alt+f2 ...

Comment: Check this: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Scrollback_buffer .

Comment: Scroll-back is not a feature of bash, it is a feature of the terminal (or console).

Comment: it can't really be unlimited, because it takes ram. besides, you are using cli server so it's reasonable to think that it's better idea to have your history constrained.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change the scrollback-buffer size using kernel options as described here: https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Scrollback_buffer .

However, if you are interested in the output of a command but at the same time you want to watch the command's progress interactively I suggest to use `tee`:

```
command | tee out.file
```

or if you want to append to a file use

```
command | tee -a out.file
```

`tee` is nice! use it! :)